# XSLT transformation for multiple font types

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am trying to make an XSLT transformation from XML, I want to transform font style tags into HTML tags, but my I am doing something wrong.
My XML file is like this one :

```
<root>
    <p>
        <span>
            <i/>
                italic
        </span>
        <span>
            <i/>
            <b/>
                bold-italic
        </span>
        <span>
                normal
        </span>
    </p>
</root>
```

What I want is HTML with the same tags but my XSLT transformation does not work:
HTML:

```
<p>
    <i>italic</i> 
    <i><b>bold-italic</b></i> 
    normal
<p>
```

I was trying xsl:if condition but it does not work,i do not know what I am doing wrong:
XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="p">
    <p>
         <xsl:for-each select="span">
             <xsl:if test="i">
                    <i>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/> 
                    </i>  
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="b">
                    <b>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/> 
                    </b>  
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each> 
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

Do you know how to repair my code ?

Comment: Before getting to your code, could you explain the **logic** behind the transformation? You have a span that contains an **empty** `<i/>` element and some text; why would that result in having the text **inside** an `<i>` element at the output?

Comment: I parsed big .odt document. The fastest way to recevive font styles was, that every span or p element appended new tag <b/>, <i/> or both of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you have more than just **b** and **i** elements? It may be possible to do this with a generic solution, that creates a nested element for each child element of a **span** element.

This solution uses a recursive template, that matches **span**, but with a parameter contain the index number of the child element that needs to be output. When this index exceeds the number of child elements, the text is output.

Try this XSLT too:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="span">
        <xsl:param name="num" select="1"/>
        <xsl:variable name="childElement" select="*[$num]"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$childElement">
                <xsl:element name="{local-name($childElement)}">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
                        <xsl:with-param name="num" select="$num + 1"/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This does assume that all the span element only contain elements you want to nest, in addition to the text.

Comment: There are only three options <b/>, <i/> and <tab/>. It looks interesing I will try this option too.

Answer (score 1):

You can test the contents of `span` element using an XPath expression with a predicate which tests for its contents, and match different templates for each situation. Since you need `b` **and** `i` for `bold-italic`, you should use that expression in one of your predicates.

The stylesheet below does the transformation using only templates (without the need of a `for-each`). I'm assuming the contents of your `<span>` elements is *text* (not mixed content):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="p">
        <p><xsl:apply-templates/></p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="span[i]">
        <i><xsl:value-of select="."/></i>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="span[b]">
        <b><xsl:value-of select="."/></b>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="span[i and b]">
        <i><b><xsl:value-of select="."/></b></i>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```